# Add either script or html code from index.html to $mdDialog?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My problem is conntected to the almighty angularjs. I consider myself a beginner, thus tips, help are very, very welcome.

I have an external chart tool, which I am trying to add to my angular web app. However, there is a problem. The chart tool is pure Javascript, plus some css files, which I added to my directory. Of course I included scripts, links into my index.html file. But the thing is that I want to display that chart in $mdDialog when clicked on a button. The button is in another html file (has its own modules, controllers, etc), and the $mdDialog has its own hmtl and controller.

In index.html the chart simply displays when an id="chart" is found.

```
<body>
<div id="chart"></div>
</body>
```

But when I add the same tags into $mdDialog nothing displays because the js file still looks for the ID on index.html.

I tried to include this solution by creating a script with src in my $mdDialog under the tags which points at the chart js file but still it doesn't work.

```
/*global angular */
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

  app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) 
      {
        if (attr.type==='text/javascript-lazy') 
        {
          var s = document.createElement("script");
          s.type = "text/javascript";                
          var src = elem.attr('src');
          if(src!==undefined)
          {
              s.src = src;
          }
          else
          {
              var code = elem.text();
              s.text = code;
          }
          document.head.appendChild(s);
          elem.remove();
        }
      }
    };
  });

}(angular));
```

Is there a way to find that ID in $mdDialog? Or do I have to make changes in the charts js file code?

Comment: I also tried to leave these tags hidden in the index.html and then to use $mdDialogs "contentElement" option which should display the choosen DOM element, but that didnt work either.

Comment: Ok fixed it temporarly. On ng-click of my button (which shows $mdDialog) added code to create a script element with src attribute of charts js file and appended it to index.html. But if there are other solutions feel free to share :) Regards